# Obter valor Inteiro em em final .00 e valor float em .01 até 0.9

Tags: java, android, int, float

Tenho este código abaixo que é de uma calculadora, porém estou com um problema: queria retornar um valor `float` quando se divide 5 / 2 = 2.5 e retornar um valor inteiro quando se divide 4 / 2 = 2 e não 2.0!

Alguém pode me ajudar quanto a isso? O código é este:

```
public class CalcActivity extends Activity
{
    TextView tvScreenCalc;
    String currentString="0",previusString=null;
    boolean isTempStringShown=false;
    int currentopperand=0;
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER_PORTRAIT);
        tvScreenCalc=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvScreenCalc);
        int numberButtons[]={R.id.button0,R.id.button1,R.id.button2,R.id.button3,R.id.button4,R.id.button5,R.id.button6,R.id.button7,R.id.button8,R.id.button9};
        NumberButtonClickListener numberClickListener=new NumberButtonClickListener();
        for(int id:numberButtons)
        { View v=findViewById(id);
            v.setOnClickListener(numberClickListener);
        }
        int opperandButtons[]={R.id.buttonPlus,R.id.buttonMinus,R.id.buttonDivide,R.id.buttonTimes,R.id.buttonDecimal,R.id.buttonClear,R.id.buttonEquals};
        OpperandButtonClickListener oppClickListener=new OpperandButtonClickListener();
        for(int id:opperandButtons)
        { View v=findViewById(id);
            v.setOnClickListener(oppClickListener);
        }
        setCurrentString("0");
    }
    void setCurrentString(String s)
    { currentString=s;
        tvScreenCalc.setText(s);
    }
    class NumberButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener
    { @Override public void onClick(View v)
    { if(isTempStringShown)
    { previusString=currentString;
        currentString="0";
        isTempStringShown=false;
    }
        String text=(String)((Button)v).getText();
        if(currentString.equals("0"))setCurrentString(text);
        else setCurrentString(currentString+text);
    }
    }
    class OpperandButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener
    { @Override public void onClick(View v)
    { int id=v.getId();
        if(id==R.id.buttonClear)
        { isTempStringShown=false;
            setCurrentString("0");
            previusString=null;
        }
        if(id==R.id.buttonDecimal)if(!currentString.contains("."))setCurrentString(currentString+".");
        if(id==R.id.buttonPlus||id==R.id.buttonMinus||id==R.id.buttonTimes||id==R.id.buttonDivide)
        { currentopperand=id;
            previusString=currentString;
            isTempStringShown=true;
        }
        if(id==R.id.buttonEquals)
        { double curr=Double.parseDouble(currentString);
            double result=0;
            if(previusString!=null)
            { double prev=Double.parseDouble(previusString);
                switch(currentopperand)
                { case R.id.buttonPlus: result=prev+curr; break;
                    case R.id.buttonMinus: result=prev-curr; break;
                    case R.id.buttonTimes: result=prev*curr; break;
                    case R.id.buttonDivide: result=prev/curr; break;
                }
            }
            setCurrentString(Double.toString(result));
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Só usar algum formatador que, quando for apenas zero apos a virgula, remova a casa decimal, nao precisa trocar o tipo

Comment: E como faço isso? Sou novo na programação, e nas pesquisas que faço, nunca aparece o que eu quero!

Comment: Se nas pesquisas que faz não aparece o que quer, é porque não está a fazer as pesquisas certas! :D. Parecendo que não ainda é preciso ter algum conhecimento para saber o que procurar. Como pequeno aparte, comece por indentar o código quem tem muito mais impacto e efeitos positivos do que possa pensar. Em relação ao problema em si, pode ver se o resultado da divisão é igual ao mesmo resultado convertido em `(int)`, isso permite-lhe saber se deveria ter decimais ou não.

Answer (score 5):

Tem muitas maneiras, eis algumas:

### Usando RegEx

```
static String autocasas(double numero)
{
   return String.valueOf(numero).replaceAll("(\\.?0+|\\.)$","");
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/EpF8qO)**.

Basicamente estamos trocando qualquer quantidade de zeros (`0+`) no final da linha (`$`) por "vazio" (`""`), e em seguida trocando qualquer ponto no final da linha também por vazio.

### Usando operações de String

```
static String autocasas(double numero)
{
   String[] partes = String.valueOf(numero).split("\\.");
   if (partes[1].equals("0")) return String.valueOf(partes[0]);
   return String.valueOf(partes[0]) + "," + String.valueOf(partes[1]);
}
```

Resultado:

```
System.out.println(autocasas(5.0/7.0)); // 0,7142857142857143
System.out.println(autocasas(5.0/2.0)); // 2,5
System.out.println(autocasas(123));     // 123
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/s0IDNY)**.

Basicamente estamos dividindo a *string* em um *array* pelo ponto decimal.

- Como estamos usando um `double`, sempre vai haver um ponto decimal para dividir;
- se a segunda parte for um zero "solto", retorna só a primeira;
- se tiver duas, concatena com uma vírgula.

Note que é uma base apenas, depois você otimiza.

Comment: **NOTA:** com float também funciona normalmente. Veja: https://ideone.com/clo5Dg

Comment: Poderia me mostrar como meu código ficaria? Como falei, sou muito ruim em programação, e não faço ideia de onde e como faço pra adapta-lo ao meu código! ;(

Comment: Ei @Bacco, valeus amigao, quer dizer que eh assim que trato o "." para passar como parâmetro de ".split()", caramba man, nao sabia, kkkk,
apanhei aqui e tive de fazer a famosa "gambi", e peor, kkkk, passei a "gambi" na reposta, rererere

Comment: agora te pergunto, porque tem de ter duas "\\", tu saberia dizer?

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho o split aceita uma expressão regular, não uma string comum; O ponto sozinho significa "qualquer caractere". A primeira barra invertida é pra escapar a barra seguinte (para o Java), a segunda é para escapar o ponto. Ou seja, em java \\ vira \ numa string. Em regex, `\.` vira o caractere "ponto" literalmente. O `$` em RegEx significa "fim da linha, e a sequência `0+$` significa "um ou mais zeros no fim da linha". Treine aqui: http://regexpal.com

Comment: @DennisWadson basta copiar a função "autocasas" do jeito que está e usar no seu código.

Comment: pow, bom saber, talvez por achar um detalhe insignificante nao procurei ir atras, mesmo porque a gambi funcionava, mas assim limpa bem o código, 
valeus mano veio!

Comment: Então é só eu por em qualquer parte do código?

Comment: @Bacco, colei teu código lá, mas não sei como usar? Pode me explicar em que parte colo ele?

Comment: setCurrentString(autocasas(result));

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma simples de perceber se o resultado tem parte decimal ou não é comparando com a conversão do valor em inteiro. Ou seja para saber se `2.5` não tem parte decimal seria fazer `2.5 == (int)2.5` que lhe iria dar falso.

Para obter um `float` com duas casas depois da virgula pode usar [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) usando `%.2f` como especificador de formato.

Combinando estas duas ideias pode ter a seguinte função para obter o resultado como `String`:

```
public static String obterResultadoFormatado(float res){
    if (res == (int)res){
        return String.valueOf((int)res);
    }
    else {
        return String.format("%.2f", res);
    }
}
```

Que depois chama diretamente com o resultado do calculo:

```
float num1 = 5;
float num2 = 4;

Log.d("CalcActivity", obterResultadoFormatado(num1 / 2)); // 2,50
Log.d("CalcActivity", obterResultadoFormatado(num2 / 2)); // 2
```

Comment: Poderia me mostrar como meu código ficaria? Como falei, sou muito ruim em programação, e não faço ideia de onde e como faço pra adapta-lo ao meu código! ;(

Answer (score 0):

Eu costumo fazer assim nesses casos:

```
// ...
float vf = 5/2;
String [] vs = String.valueOf(vf).replace(".","_").split("_");
int vi = Integer.parseInt(vs[0]);
// ...
```

no caso acima, tive problemas com `split(".")` uma certa vez, por isso usei `realce(".","_")` para evitar.

esse trecho de código faz o seguinte:
Converte a tua variavela float para uma string com `String.valueOf(...);`.
Separa ela em duas usando `...replace(...,...).split(...);`.
Depois pega a primeira parte do vetor criado e converte ele para inteiro novamente com `Integer.parseInt(...);`.

espero que seja isso que voce esteja querendo.

Comment: Poderia me mostrar como meu código ficaria? Como falei, sou muito ruim em programação, e não faço ideia de onde e como faço pra adapta-lo ao meu código! ;(